# How can I give values to an array in structure in C without any functions?

Tags: c

How can I write the program below without any functions like `strcpy()`?
I know that we can do it with functions but I want to know learn how to do it without any function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct name
{
    char fname[100];
};

struct list
{
    struct name m;
};


int main()
{
    struct list l;
    strcpy(l.m.fname,"hello");
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `strcpy` actually does? (If so, it shouldn't be hard to write it yourself, especially if the string is always "hello")

Comment: `struct name nm = { "hello" }; l.m = nm;` or `l.m = (struct name){ "hello" };`

Answer (score 3):

With C99 (or newer):

```
l.m = (struct name){"hello"};
```

That's a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). See it [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bbb257298984388).

Note that it only works if the array is inside a `struct`, as in your original, because C does not allow direct assignment to an array.

All the same, the `strcpy` may be slightly faster, because it will only copy six bytes, while the compound literal assignment above copies 100.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would pretty much require writing out the code behind the function itself. Either that or you could hardcode every value.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have to just expand out the code that would be in strcpy, which is just simple loop copying over each character until it hits the null terminator at the end..

```
{
  struct list l;
  const char *in = "hello";
  char *out = l.m.fname;
  while (*in)
    *out++ = *in++;
  }
  *out=0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, but there's a reason the standard loop is `while ((*out++ = *in++) != '\0') ;` or `while (*out++ = *in++) ;` with a null loop body and the copying in the condition — it is more compact without the extra assignment after the loop.